# Auto-filling cells with MAX, MIN, Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My project needs to span two years, so I will rely a lot on the autofill feature for my formulas. The problem is when I go and autofill MAX, MIN, AVERAGE functions, it does not autofill the way I want it to.

Here is what I need to happen when I autofill:

> Day 1 | =MIN(A1:A1)
>   Day 2 | =MIN(A1:A2)
>   Day 3 | =MIN(A1:A3)
>   Day 4 | =MIN(A1:A4)
>   Day 5 | =MIN(A1:A5)
>   Day 6 | =MIN(A1:A6)
>   Day 7 | =MIN(A1:A7)

I need the first cell to remain fixed, but be able to have the last cell increase by one cell each day, but the Autofill feature does not work that way.

Or is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

In **B1** enter:

```
=MIN($A$1:A1)
```

and copy down

Comment: Thanks, now I feel dumb because I came across that answer before.

Comment: @Thylorion  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Better use VBA instead of doing the same manually, you can use this one with timer code.

Sub Smallest()

Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMin As Double

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

dblMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)

End Sub

This is a simple VBA code will help you to set Time to run the Macro,, 
Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:00:00"), Procedure:="MyMacro", Schedule:=True